# Memory alignment in C: How is offset factoring in the return address?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, memory-alignment

I came across following code [here](https://gist.github.com/dblalock/255e76195676daa5cbc57b9b36d1c99a).

```
/* Allocate aligned memory in a portable way.
 *
 * Memory allocated with aligned alloc *MUST* be freed using aligned_free.
 *
 * @param alignment The number of bytes to which memory must be aligned. This
 *  value *must* be <= 255.
 * @param bytes The number of bytes to allocate.
 * @param zero If true, the returned memory will be zeroed. If false, the
 *  contents of the returned memory are undefined.
 * @returns A pointer to `size` bytes of memory, aligned to an `alignment`-byte
 *  boundary.
 */
void *aligned_alloc(size_t alignment, size_t size, bool zero) {
    size_t request_size = size + alignment;
    char* buf = (char*)(zero ? calloc(1, request_size) : malloc(request_size));

    size_t remainder = ((size_t)buf) % alignment;
    size_t offset = alignment - remainder;
    char* ret = buf + (unsigned char)offset;

    // store how many extra bytes we allocated in the byte just before the
    // pointer we return
    *(unsigned char*)(ret - 1) = offset;

    return (void*)ret;
}

/* Free memory allocated with aligned_alloc */
void aligned_free(void* aligned_ptr) {
    int offset = *(((char*)aligned_ptr) - 1);
    free(((char*)aligned_ptr) - offset);
}
```

Explanation:

> `char *ret = buf + (unsigned char)offset;` here, we're setting a new pointer which is ahead of base address of buf by offset bytes.
>
> > E.g. we want to allocate 68 bytes in a 16-bit aligned memory it would look something like this:
> >
> > 1. `requested_size = 68+16 = 84` and let's assume base address of buf is `buf = 0x112223341` then
> > 2. `remainder = sizeof(buf)%16 = (84%16) = 4`
> > 3. `offset = 16 - 4 = 12 (i.e. 0x0C)`
> > 4. `ret = &buf + offset = 0x11223341+0x0C = 0x1122334D`

**Questions**:

What does following line do ?
I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding this syntax and thus implementation that results.

> `*(unsigned char*)(ret - 1) = offset`

When we return `ret` what happens to the extra bytes those were allocated but never part of the base address of `ret` ? i.e. if we allocate 16 extra bytes, but only needed 12 bytes for alignment, what happens to rest of the bytes?

=======UPDATE ON CODE IN QUESTION=======

thanks to @ThomasMailund and his insights, I think I can safely modify above code in question to simplify some of the type casting as following:

```
/* Allocate aligned memory in a portable way.
 *
 * Memory allocated with aligned alloc *MUST* be freed using aligned_free.
 *
 * @param alignment The number of bytes to which memory must be aligned. This
 *  value *must* be <= 255.
 * @param bytes The number of bytes to allocate.
 * @param zero If true, the returned memory will be zeroed. If false, the
 *  contents of the returned memory are undefined.
 * @returns A pointer to `size` bytes of memory, aligned to an `alignment`-byte
 *  boundary.
 */
void *aligned_alloc(size_t alignment, size_t size, bool zero) {
    size_t request_size = size + alignment;
    unsigned char *buf = zero ? calloc(1, request_size) : malloc(request_size);

    size_t remainder = ((size_t)buf) % alignment;
    size_t offset = alignment - remainder;
    unsigned char *ret = buf + (unsigned char)offset;

    // store how many extra bytes we allocated in the byte just before the
    // pointer we return
    *(ret - 1) = offset;

    return ret;
}

/* Free memory allocated with aligned_alloc */
void aligned_free(void* aligned_ptr) {
    int offset = *(((char*)aligned_ptr) - 1);
    free(((char*)aligned_ptr) - offset);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in future who is looking at this:

I think I understand it now, when I looked at the `void aligned_free` function.
We're just saving the number of offset bytes we calculated at the address of (ret-1) and then reading it back when ready to free the memory, in order to free those additional bytes.
i.e. read the offset from `(ret-1)`, substract those many # bytes from base address we're requested to free to obtain original `buf` base address and then free up `buf` so we don't run into memory leaks !

Note: Those additional offset bytes, they're still allocated in memory, just not used !

Comment: Yes. You need to give free the same address that you got from malloc, so you need to go back there. Casting the input pointer to char * means that -1 goes one byte back, where you can get the offset you stored there. With the offset you can get the original address.

Comment: @ThomasMailund basically what I am understanding is, char * holds an address that is 4 byte long (assuming its a 32-bit machine), but we iterate over it's value 1 byte at a time, correct? If this was (int *) it would be an addition of 4 bytes instead of 1, am I understanding this right?

Comment: It is not just a question of leaks. If you didn’t adjust the pointer before free you would get undefined behavior. You can’t free parts of a block you malloc by calling free on an offset into it. The runtime system has expectations about pointers you give free() and if it isn’t an address you got from malloc or one of its three siblings, you are heading for trouble.

Comment: char is the minimal addressable unit. Typically a byte, yes. You can point char * anywhere. It is not so much how much memory it points at, but what pointer arithmetic is doing. Add or subtract to a pointer and you move the address sizeof() the underlying type (with some restrictions). For char * sizeof() is 1. So if a char is a byte, and p is char *, then p - 1 is one byte before p. If ip is int * and sizeof(int) is 4, then ip - 1 would be four bytes before ip. It is not standard compliant to do pointer arithmetic on void * so casting is necessary.

Comment: If your compiler is compliant with C11, though, you shouldn’t use this code. There is an aligned_alloc in the standard now.

Comment: Yep, i was just trying to figure out how would I do it in order to understand memory aligned addresses and their allocations and related underlying mechanics. Thanks for the spot on answers ! much appreciated !

Comment: Well, when I wrote “casting is necessary” above I was a little wrong. Casting or assigning to another pointer type is necessary. There are several unnecessary casts in the code. It is never necessary to cast to and from void when an assignment will do. So assigning void * to another type, or returning a char * as void * doesn’t require casts. But the cast to go one byte down is necessary, and of course it is necessary to cast to dereference if we haven’t assigned to a pointer of the appropriate type.

Comment: you are very welcome. I’m working on a book on C pointers and have been playing a lot with code exactly like this recently, and it is always a pleasure :)

Comment: Makes sense, the point about casting char * as void * while returning.
Can you elabore about `*(unsigned int*) (ret-1) = offset` ?
Paste a link here to purchase when it's published, happy to buy a copy of a good book ! thanks and good luck with book!

Comment: i think it would go against the rules to promote my book in comments here, but it will appear on my profile when it is out early next year. Thanks

Comment: Thanks ! one last question, can you explain why did we have to type case `(ret-1)`  ? `ret` is a `char *`, so naturally just `(ret -1) = offset` would have sufficed ?

Comment: (ret - 1) is a char pointer but it isn’t something you can assign to (a so-called lvalue). You can assign to variables or you can write into addresses, but if you tried (res - 1) = offset you would be trying to change the address (res-1) into something else. That is meaningless. What the code actually does is *(res-1) = offset. Here, *(res-1) is what the address points to, so you write a value into that address. Casting really has nothing to do with it, except that the type of offset must be something we can put into the type on the left.

Comment: you could avoid the cast if res was unsigned char * to begin with, instead of char *. Why it isn’t is something i don’t understand about the code. You could avoid a lot of casting with unsigned chars throughout.